# gdm3: change default wm from gnome to i3

Tags: gnome, window-manager, i3

When I login from gdm3 with 'System Default' selected, my (debian based) system starts gnome. I don't want to choose i3 every time I boot, rather set i3 as 'System Default'. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What Distribution?

Comment: @Bahamut based on debian

Comment: Try this . `update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` I am not sure if it works with i3. I have only experience with openbox.

Comment: Another way in $HOME/.dmrc `[Desktop]
Session=i3`

Comment: Edit ~/.xinitrc   change the exec gnome3/gdm to exec i3 / or i3wm. (I think dpkg-reconfigure gdm lets you choose the display manager)

Comment: @Bahamut Your first suggestion returns `There is only one alternative in link group x-session-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-session-manager): /usr/bin/gnome-session
Nothing to configure.`

Your second suggestion doesn't change anything

Comment: @MichaelD. I have already tried that, without success.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` doesn't return anything

Comment: I just changed to lightdm and it works :)

Comment: yes, on ubuntu it's lightdm :)

Comment: @MichaelD. I don't use Ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

Gnome 3 has changed how user defaults are stored (and now direct manipulation appears to require root privileges).  Per the Gnome page for [Configure a user default session](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-user.html.en):

> To specify a default session for a user, update the user’s account service in the
>
> `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/username` file:

```
 [User]
 Language=
 XSession=i3
```

That should set the *`username`* to use the i3 session on the next login.

However, I should note that this is **not** changing the System Default - a different (new) user logging into the machine will still get gnome.  That said, your question really seems to be about changing it for *you* (versus the system as a whole), and this will do that.